# AWS connect to windows ec2 instance via FTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I am trying to connect to an amazon EC2 windows instance via ftp with no success. Can someone please guide me through the steps?

Comment: There are multiple intermediate things that could be at play here, so can you describe what you've done so far to configure your instance? Is it in a publicly-accessible subnet? Is it in a private subnet? Have you configured the security group associated with the instance to allow incoming connections to the port the FTP server is running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use FTP, you will need to:

- Run an FTP server on your Windows EC2 instance
- Open the Security Group associated with your instance on Port 21 (FTP)
- Connect to the server via a Public IP address
- Assumption: Your instance is in a public subnet